# Перестал работать метод после переписывания на ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Взял [метод форматирования](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format) строк в JS из ответа на en.SO и адаптировал под свои нужды. Изначально все было написано в глобальных переменных и работало.

Но глобальные переменные это не есть хорошо, добавил функцию-обертку и экспортировал.

```
/*Format string */
export function formatString() {
   if (!String.prototype.formatString) {
      String.prototype.formatString = function() {
      var args = arguments;
         return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
            ? args[number]
            : match;
         });
      };
   }
}
```

В другом скрипте произвел импорт и использовал:

```
import 'fileWithFormatStringMethod.js'

....
a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/{0}".formatString(dataFormat));
....
```

В консоли получил ошибку:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: "image/{0}".formatString is not a function
```

Пробовал в вызывающем файле явно импортировать метод

```
import { formatString } from 'fileWithFormatStringMethod.js'
```

Из этого же файла без проблем импортируются классы

```
 import { elementByClass, elementById } from 'fileWithFormatStringMethod.js'
```

Подскажите, что я сделал неправильно?

Comment: Импортировали функцию но не вызвали ее. Поэтому прототип остался неизмененным и ошибка возникла.

Comment: да, забыл указать. пробовал импортировать методы явно, но результат тот же. из этого же файла импортируются классы без проблем инструкцией export

Comment: надо в данном случае импортировать метод так: `import {formatString} from 'pathToFile';` Это надо сделать в точке инициализации приложения. и сразу после вызвать метод `formatString`, чтобы переопределить метод в объекте `String`. Но сам подход странный. Почему просто не сделать её чистой функцией? @while1pass импорт лишь дает ссылку на метод, но не выполняет его

Comment: @while1pass, синтакс импортов рабочий, просто я привык к более подробному. Проблема собственно объяснена в первом моем комментарии

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев могу задать глупый вопрос, но поясните, что значит сразу сделать "чистой функцией"?

Comment: @while1pass, смотрите у вас _две_ фунцкии formatString. Первая - при вызове дописывает возможность вызывать вторую ко всем строкам. Вы в своем коде импортируете первую (просто берете ее, не вызываете), а пробуете вызвать - вторую. Так как первая не отработала, второй - нету.

Comment: @while1pass https://goo.gl/GfS7yE. Чистая функция – особый вид функции, возвращающей значения, которая не только не имеет побочных эффектов, но и не зависит от побочных эффектов остального кода – к примеру, не работает с глобальными переменными, которые могут быть случайно изменены где-то ещё. Чистая функция, будучи вызванной с одними и теми же аргументами, возвращает один и тот же результат. Т.е. вашу функцию можно сделать так: вы передаете в неё строку, и возвращается обработанная строка. И не  надо вклиниваться в глобальные объекты и добавлять им обработчики

Comment: @while1pass, чистая фукнция - это грубо говоря штука которая принимает что-то, и на основании этого возвращает предсказуемый результат и больше ничего не меняет, не вызывает и не требует за пределами себя. Никаких прототипов глобальных переменных и прочего.

Comment: @while1pass `Подскажите, что я сделал неправильно?` вы не вызываете методы.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка из вашего ответа "Так как первая не отработала, второй - нету." как заставить отработать первую?

Comment: import {formatString} from 'fileWithFormatStringMethod.js';
formatString();

Но лучше сделайте как вам сказал @ВасилийБарбашев

Comment: То есть написать функцию, возвращающую отформатированную строку, и возвращать ее из модуля, без модификации прототипов.

Comment: скажите, а что Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка сделал, спасибо за советы, если можно улучшить код, отпишитесь

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев сделал, спасибо за советы, если можно улучшить код, отпишитесь

Comment: @OlmerDale форматировать строку

Comment: вот если бы Вы сказали как конкретно, то возможно получили бы более точный и правильный ответ. А так  - форматируйте !)

Comment: @OlmerDale заменой вставок {}  как на питоне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С использованием стрелочных функций можно уменьшить количество кода:

```
export const formatString = (s, p) => 
    s.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, (match, number) => p[number] || match);

// ...
import { formatString } from '...';
```

И ещё немного другой вариант функции, чтобы параметры передавать не в массиве, а в объекте с ключами (нужно поменять только рег. выражение на `/{(.*?)}/g`):

```
export const formatString = (s, p) => 
    s.replace(/{(.*?)}/g, (match, key) => p[key] || match);

formatString('image/{id}/', { id: 123 }); // "image/123/"
formatString('image/{id}/{size}', { id: 123, size: '100x100' }); // "image/123/100x100"
```

Comment: лаконично. только стрелочные функции не так наглядны, на мой взгляд

Answer (score 2):

Переписал функцию с учетом рекомендаций [Умеренно Упоротая Утка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14963/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) и [Василий Барбашев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/205877/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2)

```
export default function formatString(string, args) {
    return string.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
        return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match
        ;
    });
}
```

Использование:

```
 a.href = canvas.toDataURL(formatString("image/{0}", [dataFormat,]));
```

Если можно улучшить код, отпишитесь, пожалуйста

Comment: можно не проверять на `typeof args[number]`, а сразу писать `return args[number] ? args[number] : match;`, а если вы пишите на es6 то http://pastebin.com/iJ7335b1, если в файле будет набор методов, то лучше использовать `export const functionString = (...) => ...`, тогда импортировать нужно будет по имени через `{formatString}`

Comment: или вообще в условие `args[number] || match` http://pastebin.com/Epya1Lc3 но это все не важно :)